# Angular.js detect when controller is shown/rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In Angular.js can I detect when a controller (well really a view) is shown/rendered?

**Usecase:**
I have 2 tabs. Each tab is a controller; History Controller and Print Controller. When you click a tab; a history of test results is shown (History controller) OR a list of links to pdfs is shown (Print controller). I want to detect whenever a controller is 'shown'/rendered, ie whenever you click a tab I want to perform some custom code.

Is there an angular.js controller method I can use? Maybe `Controller::onRender` or something? Or should I stick to standard JQuery and implement some code on the tab click event?

Ie, whats a Angular.js solution/implementation to this usecase?

Comment: There's a difference between it being shown vs. rendered, so which do you have in mind? And if you're showing a view using a parent scope or controller, you shouldn't have to detect any changes; _you're_ the one making them. Lastly, try not to use jQuery for anything but a last resort.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein thanks for your comment. Will rendered fire whenever I change tabs? Thats what I want. So I think I want show (if that will fire whenever I change tabs). Essentially I want to execute code when a tab (Controller) is showing

Comment: checkout $viewContentLoaded event, or ng-init...

Comment: Are you making your own tabs? Or are you using a plugin to do it? (Angularjs material, bootstrap, etc). With that info I can help you, but as an advice, if you want to re-render the tabs in each click, consider to use `ng-if` instead `ng-show` or `ng-class`

Comment: @The.Bear has an excellent point about browser vs. in-page tabs. Do be careful, though, not to have HTTP calls that get fired in tabs you intend to render over and over.